# Lightning Component LockerService - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: text

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to get ready for the upcoming LockerService critical update and I am seeing this error when loading my components/apps:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: text
throws at https://opic--icareuat.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/C9w03EpEHI__XcCDlMV8MQ/aura_prod.js:513:306
```

It seems to be an issue with the Salesforce js file, anyone know what this cause is and how to get around it?

Comment: The error source is the root cause of the problem. It is not the source of problem. Please check the javascript controller invoking the Salesforce js code.

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like

```
var text = '1515415' ;
```

and in the same context (probably same JS method), another definition of variable test

```
var text = 'dfhdfghf' ;
```